# How to pass a PHP var to an external js file

Tags: javascript, php

I know there are numerous resource that covers this topic but I couldn't find one that matched my problem completely.  I am trying to pass $filemanagerToken to post_editor.js.  Here is what I have;

In index.php i have the following script:

```
    $filemanagerToken = '123456';
    $this->data['scripts_admin'] = '
    <!-- Scripts Admin -->
    <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.16.0/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="'.base_url().'/assets/admin/post/js/post_editor.js">
        var fmKey = '.json_encode($filemanagerToken).';
    </script>';
```

And in post_editor.js, I have the following;

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'post_body' ,{
    filebrowserBrowseUrl : '../../filemanager/dialog.php?type=2&editor=ckeditor&fldr=',
    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : '../../filemanager/dialog.php?type=1&editor=ckeditor&fldr=&akey=fmKey' ,
});
```

I just cannot understand how to echo out fmKey above.  Any guidance appreciated.  I tried  but get a parse error.

Comment: In the `CKEDITOR` code snippet is presumably where you want to use this `fmKey` - so perhaps `filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : '../../filemanager/dialog.php?type=1&editor=ckeditor&fldr=&akey='+fmKey`

Comment: I tried '+fmKey,    but I get an error, Uncaught ReferenceError: fmKey is not defined
    at post_editor.js:4

Comment: A `<script>` element with a `src` doesn't take inline js. Place `var fmKey = '.json_encode($filemanagerToken).';` in its own `<script>..</script>` element

Comment: Thanks Brombeer.  How would I capture the var in the js file?  Assume you mean, 

              <script>
              var fmKey = '.json_encode($filemanagerToken).';
              </script>

I still get Uncaught ReferenceError: fmKey is not defined
    at post_editor.js:4

Comment: Add the script block where you define `fmKey` first, before you load the `post_editor.js` file to make sure it exists before your code tries to use it. And it should probably then be `&akey=' + fmKey` or it will be sent as the string `fmKey`.